# IFS condition between two values isn't working properly

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

This is an IFS formula I wrote in Google Sheets:

```
IFS(B5=1,"Same", B5=-1,"Same", B5>1,"Narrower", B5<-1,"Narrower", B5=0,"Linear", 0>B5<1,"Wider")
```

Whenever I enter a value for B5 between 0 and 1, such as  0.5, it says there is "no match".

I think there is something wrong with the last section of the code. I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
0<B5<1
```

use

```
AND(B5>0,B5<1)
```

because the first is not a supported sintax.

Answer (score 0):

[Rubén's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122339/) correctly identifies and corrects your error.

Your code can also be simplified by incorporating the ABS function instead of mirroring  conditions for both positive and negative numbers.

For example `ABS(n)=1` is equivalent to `OR(n=1,n=-1)` and `ABS(n)>1`is equivalent to `OR(n>1,n<-1)`.

Incorporating [Rubén's correction](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122339/) your formula could be reduced to:

```
IFS(ABS(B5)=1,"Same",
    ABS(B5)>1,"Narrower",
    B5=0,"Linear",
    AND(B5>0,B5<1),"Wider"))
```

Based on the pattern above, I suspect your next step may have been to add `AND(B5<0,B5>-1),"Wider")`. If that is the case ABS can be used again:

```
IFS(ABS(B5)=1,"Same",
    ABS(B5)>1,"Narrower",
    B5=0,"Linear",
    AND(ABS(B5)>0,ABS(B5)<1),"Wider"))
```